# Do hound attacks increase close to the 200th day?

Tags: dont-starve, dont-starve-together

Is it true that hound attacks get increasingly vicious and happen almost everyday if we don't level up by day 200 or so?

Comment: I don't think so, according to the [Don't Starve wiki](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Hound) they periodically attack every 3–13 days. They are more frequent in Sandbox Mode, though.

Comment: Another thing to note is that the warning given that Hounds are coming will provide shorter and shorter notice as they happen.

Answer (score 3):

No. The most severe hound attack tier is past day 100, at which point they can attack every 3-7 days in groups of 7-10.